# Velocity Variable(use together string and integer variables)

Tags: velocity, xwiki

How can I use **String and Integer variable**s it together in "**Velocity**"?

```
#set ($var1 = "exp"+1)
```

I tried a few times but I could not.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you were trying to do concatenation, it's not supported by Velocity, not even for 2 Strings. Instead, you should use string interpolation. Example:

```
#set ($string = "exp")
#set ($number = 1)
#set ($interpolatedExample1 = "$string$number")
#set ($interpolatedExample2 = "${string}someStringLiteral$number")
```

Read more details and examples in the [documentation](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/user-guide.html#string-concatenation).